# How to explain the bit right shift two different results?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I get two different results, I'm confused, the code is :

```
int main () 
{
    int i = 0xcffffff3;
    printf("%x\n", 0xcffffff3>>2);
    printf("%x\n", i>>2);

    return 0;
}
```

*the result is :*

> **33fffffc
>
>       f3fffffc**

Comment: Shifting a signed integer to the right has implementation defined behavior.  And you are seeing that.

Comment: @StoryTeller What about left shift? Will that be implementation defined too?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - [No, it's either correct or flat out undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4)

Comment: I want know the `f3fffffc` how to calc it?

Comment: Please don't do crazy things and ask SO users to explain the crazy~:(

Comment: @levonfly the arithmetic shift is equivalent to multiplication (left shift) or division (right shift) of whole numbers: `x >> y == x / pow(2, y)` so if you want `f3fffffc` (the arithmetic shift result) you can calculate `i / 4` or `(int)0xcffffff3 / 4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all comes down to `0xcffffff3`. That is an hexadecimal integer constant. The type of the constant depends on its magnitude. Let's refer to [C11 § 6.4.4.1 ¶ 5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.
>
> **Octal or Hexadecimal Constant** - int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, unsigned long long int

So assuming 32 bit integer representation on your system. The type of `0xcffffff3` is unsigned int.

Now, when you do `int i = 0xcffffff3;` the unsigned constant is converted to a signed integer. This conversion yields a negative value.

Finally, when right shifting, it has the semantics defined by [C11 §6.5.7 ¶5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup> . If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

Shifting the unsigned constant yields `0xcffffff3/4` and shifting `i` yields an implementation defined value (a negative integer in this case).

Comment: Good to have a standard focused answer around. I just always feel a tad bit bad for C beginners who stumble upon UB literally the moment they start moving from their first hello world :)

Comment: Actually, was it already an implementation defined value in C99 or was it UB? The wording of "implementation-defined value" is a slightly different beast now that I think about it.

Comment: @grek40 - I don't have C99 handy, but if memory serves it was implementation defined there as well, not UB.

Answer (score 3):

In `0xcffffff3 >> 2`, both values are treated as `unsigned` while in `i >> 2`, `i` is `signed`.

As a result, the arithmetic shift is prepending `1` bits in the signed case because the number is negative before shifting.

Use `(unsigned)i >> 2` or define `unsigned i = 0xcffffff3;` if you want the same result as with the constants.

Comment: This answer is a typical C pitfall... it kindof explains things but it's not accurately covering the C standard, where (as I just read) probably any shift on signed numbers (no matter left or right) is plain old undefined behavior. So be warned, I don't have time to include the whole standard into the answer for now

Comment: Spelling it out a bit more, `int i = 0xcffffff3;` causes implementation-defined behaviour that , on OP's system, has given `i` a negative value